# Missing values in JSON in R function

Tags: r, json, twitter

I'm using the following function to extract the retweet ids from a tweet JSON file (to build retweet cascades). Here is a part of the code in R:

```
parse_raw_tweets_to_cascades <- function(path, batch = 1000, cores = 1, output_path = NULL, keep_user = F, keep_absolute_time = F, keep_text = F, keep_retweet_count = F, progress = T, return_as_list = T, save_temp = F, api_version=2) { 
  check_required_packages(c('jsonlite', 'data.table', 'bit64'))
  library(data.table)
  # a helper function
  zero_if_null <- function(count) {
    ifelse(is.null(count), 0, count)
  }

if (api_version == 2) {
    parse_tweet <- function(tweet, keep_text = F) {
      tryCatch({
        json_tweet <- jsonlite::fromJSON(tweet)
        if (is.null(json_tweet$includes) || is.null(json_tweet$includes$users)) {
          stop('The author information is required!')
        }
        id <- json_tweet$data$id
        magnitude <-zero_if_null(json_tweet$includes$users$public_metrics$followers_count)
        user_id <- json_tweet$data$author_id
        username <- json_tweet$user$username 
        retweet_id <- NA
        #print(typeof(id)) #character    
        #cat(sprintf('id is: %s \n', id))
        cat(sprintf('magnitude is: %d \n', magnitude))

        if (keep_text) text <- json_tweet$data$text
        if (!is.null(json_tweet$data$referenced_tweets) && json_tweet$data$referenced_tweets$type == 'retweeted') {
          #if this tweet is a retweet, get original tweet's information
          retweet_id <- json_tweet$data$referenced_tweets$id  
          cat("retweet_id: ", retweet_id, "\n")
          if (keep_text) text <- NA 
       }
        cat("Monaaaaa", "\n")
        res <- list(id = id, magnitude = magnitude, user_id = user_id,
                    username = username, retweet_id = retweet_id) 
        if (keep_text) res[['text']] <- text
        res
      },
      .... # warning for error processing json 
        )
   }
}
```

**This is the error I receive:**

> Error processing json: Error in if
> (!is.null(json_tweet$data$referenced_tweets) &&
> json_tweet$data$referenced_tweets$type == : missing value where
> TRUE/FALSE needed

**Question:**
I don't know why the retweet ids are null.
I checked my json file and searched for `retweeted`. I see the path (`json_tweet$data$referenced_tweets$type`) is correct.

**NOTE:** The above function is part of the [evently library](https://github.com/monanasery/evently). The package works fine with [their sample data provided on Github](https://github.com/monanasery/evently/blob/master/inst/extdata/tweets_anonymized.jsonl) which is in Twitter API V1 format, but **it doesn't work with my JSON file which is in V2**.

Here is a small part of my data (part of JSON for retweets of one user):

```
{"data": [{"referenced_tweets": [{"type": "retweeted", "id": "1253739069273710594"}], "entities": {"mentions": [{"start": 3, "end": 16, "username": "warriors_mom", "id": "75184478"}, {"start": 18, "end": 24, "username": "AC360", "id": "227837742"}], "annotations": [{"start": 25, "end": 39, "probability": 0.7096, "type": "Person", "normalized_text": "President Trump"}], "urls": [{"start": 98, "end": 121, "url": "", "expanded_url": "", "display_url": "", "images": [{"url": "", "width": 144, "height": 144}, {"url": "", "width": 144, "height": 144}], "status": 200, "title": "Ultraviolet Irradiation of Blood: \u201cThe Cure That Time Forgot\u201d?", "description": "Ultraviolet blood irradiation (UBI) was extensively used in the 1940s and 1950s to treat many diseases including septicemia, pneumonia, tuberculosis, arthritis, asthma and even poliomyelitis. The early studies were carried out by several physicians in ...", "unwound_url": ""}]}, "public_metrics": {"retweet_count": 3, "reply_count": 0, "like_count": 0, "quote_count": 0}, "possibly_sensitive": false, "reply_settings": "everyone", "lang": "en", "id": "1253834847258370048", "context_annotations": [{"domain": {"id": "3", "name": "TV Shows", "description": "Television shows from around the world"}, "entity": {"id": "10000271509", "name": "Anderson Cooper 360", "description": "Anderson Cooper goes beyond the headlines with in-depth reporting and investigations. Through nightly \"Keeping Them Honest\" reports, Anderson keeps his commitment to holding those in power accountable. And, of course, there's the RidicuList, a tongue-in-cheek commentary on the day's news that may leave viewers (and Anderson) laughing. Joining him are guests that frequently include political and legal analysts."}}, {"domain": {"id": "4", "name": "TV Episodes", "description": "Television show episodes"}, "entity": {"id": "1249271407508242432", "name": "Anderson Cooper 360", "description": "Anderson Cooper goes beyond the headlines with in-depth reporting and investigations. Through nightly \"Keeping Them Honest\" reports, Anderson keeps his commitment to holding those in power accountable. And, of course, there's the RidicuList, a tongue-in-cheek commentary on the day's news that may leave viewers (and Anderson) laughing. Joining him are guests that frequently include political and legal analysts."}}, {"domain": {"id": "4", "name": "TV Episodes", "description": "Television show episodes"}, "entity": {"id": "1249277031881138178", "name": "Anderson Cooper 360", "description": "Anderson Cooper goes beyond the headlines with in-depth reporting and investigations. Through nightly \"Keeping Them Honest\" reports, Anderson keeps his commitment to holding those in power accountable. And, of course, there's the RidicuList, a tongue-in-cheek commentary on the day's news that may leave viewers (and Anderson) laughing. Joining him are guests that frequently include political and legal analysts."}}, {"domain": {"id": "4", "name": "TV Episodes", "description": "Television show episodes"}, "entity": {"id": "1250891078401552385", "name": "Anderson Cooper 360", "description": "Anderson Cooper goes beyond the headlines with in-depth reporting and investigations. Through nightly \"Keeping Them Honest\" reports, Anderson keeps his commitment to holding those in power accountable. And, of course, there's the RidicuList, a tongue-in-cheek commentary on the day's news that may leave viewers (and Anderson) laughing. Joining him are guests that frequently include political and legal analysts."}}, {"domain": {"id": "10", "name": "Person", "description": "Named people in the world like Nelson Mandela"}, "entity": {"id": "799022225751871488", "name": "Donald Trump", "description": "45th US President, Donald Trump"}}, {"domain": {"id": "29", "name": "Events [Entity Service]", "description": "Entity Service related Events domain"}, "entity": {"id": "1249271407508242432", "name": "Anderson Cooper 360", "description": "Anderson Cooper goes beyond the headlines with in-depth reporting and investigations. Through nightly \"Keeping Them Honest\" reports, Anderson keeps his commitment to holding those in power accountable. And, of course, there's the RidicuList, a tongue-in-cheek commentary on the day's news that may leave viewers (and Anderson) laughing. Joining him are guests that frequently include political and legal analysts."}}, {"domain": {"id": "29", "name": "Events [Entity Service]", "description": "Entity Service related Events domain"}, "entity": {"id": "1249277031881138178", "name": "Anderson Cooper 360", "description": "Anderson Cooper goes beyond the headlines with in-depth reporting and investigations. Through nightly \"Keeping Them Honest\" reports, Anderson keeps his commitment to holding those in power accountable. And, of course, there's the RidicuList, a tongue-in-cheek commentary on the day's news that may leave viewers (and Anderson) laughing. Joining him are guests that frequently include political and legal analysts."}}, {"domain": {"id": "29", "name": "Events [Entity Service]", "description": "Entity Service related Events domain"}, "entity": {"id": "1250891078401552385", "name": "Anderson Cooper 360", "description": "Anderson Cooper goes beyond the headlines with in-depth reporting and investigations. Through nightly \"Keeping Them Honest\" reports, Anderson keeps his commitment to holding those in power accountable. And, of course, there's the RidicuList, a tongue-in-cheek commentary on the day's news that may leave viewers (and Anderson) laughing. Joining him are guests that frequently include political and legal analysts."}}, {"domain": {"id": "35", "name": "Politician", "description": "Politicians in the world, like Joe Biden"}, "entity": {"id": "799022225751871488", "name": "Donald Trump", "description": "45th US President, Donald Trump"}}], "created_at": "2020-04-24T23:54:57.000Z", "author_id": "1890848160", "text": "RT @warriors_mom: @AC360 President Trump was referring to this well-documented medical treatment: ", "source": "Twitter for iPhone", "conversation_id": "1253834847258370048"}, {"referenced_tweets": [{"type": "retweeted", "id": "1253452455540666371"}], "entities": {"mentions": [{"start": 3, "end": 16, "username": "warriors_mom", "id": "75184478"}], "annotations": [{"start": 24, "end": 27, "probability": 0.691, "type": "Place", "normalized_text": "U.S."}]}, "public_metrics": {"retweet_count": 5, "reply_count": 0, "like_count": 0, "quote_count": 0}, "possibly_sensitive": false, "reply_settings": "everyone", "lang": "en", "id": "1253828982413410307", "context_annotations": [{"domain": {"id": "123", "name": "Ongoing News Story", "description": "Ongoing News Stories like 'Brexit'"}, "entity": {"id": "1220701888179359745", "name": "COVID-19"}}], "created_at": "2020-04-24T23:31:39.000Z", "author_id": "863857568", "text": "RT @warriors_mom: Major U.S. credit-card issuers begin lowering customer spending limits as coronavirus pandemic shutdowns leave millions j\u2026", "source": "Twitter for iPhone", "conversation_id": "1253828982413410307"}, {"referenced_tweets": [{"type": "retweeted", "id": "1253815956662620163"}], "entities": {"mentions": [{"start": 3, "end": 16, "username": "warriors_mom", "id": "75184478"}, {"start": 18, "end": 32, "username": "RealMattCouch", "id": "601535938"}], "annotations": [{"start": 33, "end": 41, "probability": 0.8682, "type": "Person", "normalized_text": "Seth Rich"}]}, "public_metrics": {"retweet_count": 2, "reply_count": 0, "like_count": 0, "quote_count": 0}, "possibly_sensitive": false, "reply_settings": "everyone", "lang": "en", "id": "1253816055161651202", "created_at": "2020-04-24T22:40:16.000Z", "author_id": "1065308069645754368", "text": "RT @warriors_mom: @RealMattCouch Seth Rich", "source": "Twitter for Android", "conversation_id": "1253816055161651202"}, {"referenced_tweets": [{"type": "retweeted", "id": "1253811776103333890"}], "entities": {"mentions": [{"start": 3, "end": 16, "username": "warriors_mom", "id": "75184478"}], "annotations": [{"start": 63, "end": 67, "probability": 0.9967, "type": "Person", "normalized_text": "Trump"}, {"start": 69, "end": 74, "probability": 0.9523, "type": "Place", "normalized_text": "Russia"}, {"start": 87, "end": 95, "probability": 0.8678, "type": "Organization", "normalized_text": "Alfa Bank"}]}, "public_metrics": {"retweet_count": 1, "reply_count": 0, "like_count": 0, "quote_count": 0}, "possibly_sensitive": false, "reply_settings": "everyone", "lang": "en", "id": "1253812582806216704", "context_annotations": [{"domain": {"id": "10", "name": "Person", "description": "Named people in the world like Nelson Mandela"}, "entity": {"id": "799022225751871488", "name": "Donald Trump", "description": "45th US President, Donald Trump"}}, {"domain": {"id": "35", "name": "Politician", "description": "Politicians in the world, like Joe Biden"}, "entity": {"id": "799022225751871488", "name": "Donald Trump", "description": "45th US President, Donald Trump"}}, {"domain": {"id": "30", "name": "Entities [Entity Service]", "description": "Entity Service top level domain, every item that is in Entity Service should be in this domain"}, "entity": {"id": "848920371311001600", "name": "Technology", "description": "Technology and computing"}}, {"domain": {"id": "30", "name": "Entities [Entity Service]", "description": "Entity Service top level domain, every item that is in Entity Service should be in this domain"}, "entity": {"id": "898650876658634752", "name": "Cybersecurity", "description": "Cybersecurity"}}], "created_at": "2020-04-24T22:26:29.000Z", "author_id": "987931361963950080", "text": "RT @warriors_mom: Top cyber security team finds no evidence of Trump-Russia chatter on Alfa Bank server: A cyber security report debunks th\u2026", "source": "Twitter for Android", "conversation_id": "1253812582806216704"}, {"referenced_tweets": [{"type": "retweeted", "id": "1253461793168674821"}], "attachments": {"media_keys": ["3_1253461775980339201", "3_1253461780254392326", "3_1253461784981377024", "3_1253461788408102912"]}, "entities": {"mentions": [{"start": 3, "end": 16, "username": "warriors_mom", "id": "75184478"}], "hashtags": [{"start": 23, "end": 32, "tag": "FakeNews"}], "urls": [{"start": 56, "end": 79, "url": "", "expanded_url": "", "display_url": "pic.twitter.com/po6BRVf2pu", "media_key": "3_1253461775980339201"}, {"start": 56, "end": 79, "url": "", "expanded_url": "", "display_url": "pic.twitter.com/po6BRVf2pu", "media_key": "3_1253461780254392326"}, {"start": 56, "end": 79, "url": "", "expanded_url": "", "display_url": "pic.twitter.com/po6BRVf2pu", "media_key": "3_1253461784981377024"}, {"start": 56, "end": 79, "url": "", "expanded_url": "", "display_url": "pic.twitter.com/po6BRVf2pu", "media_key": "3_1253461788408102912"}]}, "public_metrics": {"retweet_count": 6, "reply_count": 0, "like_count": 0, "quote_count": 0}, "possibly_sensitive": false, "reply_settings": "everyone", "lang": "en", "id": "1253787731517476866", "created_at": "2020-04-24T20:47:44.000Z", "author_id": "461486301", "text": "RT @warriors_mom: Dear #FakeNews Media... seriously? \ud83d\ude44\ud83e\udd23 ", "source": "Twitter Web App", "conversation_id": "1253787731517476866"}, {"referenced_tweets": [{"type": "retweeted", "id": "1253348491805577216"}], "entities": {"mentions": [{"start": 3, "end": 16, "username": "warriors_mom", "id": "75184478"}], "annotations": [{"start": 18, "end": 23, "probability": 0.868, "type": "Organization", "normalized_text": "Amazon"}]}, "public_metrics": {"retweet_count": 2, "reply_count": 0, "like_count": 0, "quote_count": 0}, "possibly_sensitive": false, "reply_settings": "everyone", "lang": "en", "id": "1253787648180789253", "context_annotations": [{"domain": {"id": "45", "name": "Brand Vertical", "description": "Top level entities that describe a Brands industry"}, "entity": {"id": "781974596706635776", "name": "Retail"}}, {"domain": {"id": "46", "name": "Brand Category", "description": "Categories within Brand Verticals that narrow down the scope of Brands"}, "entity": {"id": "783335558466506752", "name": "Online"}}, {"domain": {"id": "47", "name": "Brand", "description": "Brands and Companies"}, "entity": {"id": "10026792024", "name": "Amazon"}}], "created_at": "2020-04-24T20:47:24.000Z", "author_id": "3003997593", "text": "RT @warriors_mom: Amazon Scooped Up Data From Its Own Sellers to Launch Competing Products: Contrary to assertions to Congress, employees o\u2026", "source": "Twitter for iPhone", "conversation_id": "1253787648180789253"}, {"referenced_tweets": [{"type": "retweeted", "id": "1253716749817729025"}], ....}
```